# Is there a way to "generalize" this python routine into a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Essentially I'd like to perform a switch statement based on the  existence of an item's value in a list and then perform calculations that item if it exists. Notice the difference `do_calculations_on()` and `do_something_else_on` methods.

```py
l = ['no','maybe','yes']

item0 = next(filter(lambda x: x == 'no', l),"default")
if item0:
    print(item0) #'no'
    do_calculations_on(item0)


item_dne = next(filter(lambda x: x == 0, l), "-1")
if not item_dne:
    print(item_dne) # -1
    
item2 = next(filter(lambda x: x == 'yes', l), "dft")
if item2:
    print(item2) #'yes'
    do_something_else_on(item2)
```

to something that looks like (pseudocode)

```
if ('yes')
    then do_calculations_on('yes')
elif ('-1')
    then print('-1')
else ('no')
    then do_something_else_on('no')
```

EDIT:
I think I have made this example more complicated than it should have been.

I am giving a list of dictionary elements that are of the form

`d = {'foo': foo_value, 'bar': bar_value}`.

I am given multiple `d` elements as a list so

`[d1,d2,..] =. [{'foo': foo_value1, 'bar': bar_value1},{'foo': foo_value2, 'bar': bar_value2},...]`

I want to know if `this_bar_value` exists in a dictionary within that list, and if it does, use the dictionary element corresponding to that value.

My attempt at doing this is to perform a "first-or-default" on the list like:

```
found_d = next(filter(lambda x: x['bar'] == 'this_bar_value',[d1,d2,..] ), {})`

if found_d:
    do_something_to(found_d)
```

But then I want to do other things when other 'bar_values' exist in a dictionary in the list and use that dictionary to perform other calculations. So essentially I want to generalize something like:

```
found_d1 = next(filter(lambda x: x['bar'] == 'this_bar_value',[d1,d2,..] ), {})`

if found_d1:
    do_something_to(found_d)


another_d = next(filter(lambda x: x['bar'] == 'new_bar_value',[d1,d2,..] ), {})`

if another_d:
    do_another_thing(another_d)
```

to something like

```
def new_method(bar_value, list_of_dictionariess):
    if bar_value == 'this_bar_value':
         do_something_to(found_d)  # having trouble thinking about how to compare bar_value and using its corresponding dictionary
    elif bar_value == 'another_bar_value':
         do_another_thing(another_d)
```

The map function below is close so, it would look like:

```
map(func, [d1,d2,...]) 

def func(d):
bar_value = d['bar']
    if bar_value == 'this_bar_value':
         do_something_to(found_d)  
    elif bar_value == 'another_bar_value':
         do_another_thing(another_d)
```

but the issue with this is that I would like to pass other parameters.i built (that are not lists) into this function, so take a look at local_var1 and local_var2.

```
local_var1 = 10
local_var2 = 12

map(func, [d1,d2,...]) 

def func(d):
    bar_value = d['bar']
    
    if bar_value == 'this_bar_value':
         do_something_to(d, local_var1)  
    elif bar_value == 'another_bar_value':
         do_another_thing(d, local_var2)
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the code and I don't see how the pseudocode is any different. Could you give a more concrete example?

Comment: just like your pseudocode, but with the necessary adjustments... python doesn't have a switch, so you need to do it with if-elif-else... or your can get creative with dictionaries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still no sure what do you want, but you can wrap your pseudocode into a function and use it in `map`:

```py
l = ['no','maybe','yes']

def func(x):
    if x == 'yes':
        # do something
        return 1
    elif x == 'no':
        # do something
        return 2
    else:
        # do something
        return 3

print(list(map(func, l)))
# -> [2, 3, 1]
```

---

**Edit based on question update:**

I believe this structure of list of dictionaries is kinda tricky. But if need to use it, and you just want to retrieve the info from your dict:

```py
def new_method(target_value, list_of_dictionaries):
    # Subset list of dictionaries to a single dictionary matching the output
    try:
        d = [{k: v for k,v in d.items() if v == target_value} for d in list_of_dictionaries if target_value in d.values()][0]
    except:
        print(f'The target_value "{target_value}" is not in dict values.')
        return None
    # Conditionals
    if target_value == 'bar_value1':
        # do something to dict subset `d`
        return d
    elif target_value == 'bar_value2':
        # do something to dict subset `d`
        return d
    else:
        return 'default_output'
```

Or if you need to update the dictionary values ***inplace***:

```py
def new_method_inplace(target_value, list_of_dictionaries):
    # Get the list index and dict key of the target dictionary
    try:
        idx, key = [(i,k) for i,d in enumerate(list_of_dictionaries) if target_value in d.values() for k,v in d.items() if v==target_value][0]
    except:
        print(f'The target_value "{target_value}" is not in dict values.')
        return None
    # Conditionals
    if target_value == 'bar_value1':
        # do something inplace to dict subset `list_of_dictionaries[idx][key]`
        list_of_dictionaries[idx][key] = 'result_of_calculation'
    elif target_value == 'bar_value2':
        # do something inplace to dict subset `list_of_dictionaries[idx][key]`
        list_of_dictionaries[idx][key] = 'result_of_calculation'
    else:
        return 'default_output'
```

**Examples:**

```py
list_of_dictionaries = [
    {'foo': 'foo_value1', 'bar': 'bar_value1'},
    {'foo': 'foo_value2', 'bar': 'bar_value2'}
]

new_method(target_value='bar_value2', list_of_dictionaries=list_of_dictionaries)
# -> {'bar': 'bar_value2'}

new_method(target_value='foo_value1', list_of_dictionaries=list_of_dictionaries)
# -> 'default_output'

new_method(target_value='inexistent_value', list_of_dictionaries=list_of_dictionaries)
# -> The target_value "inexistent_value" is not in dict values.

new_method_inplace(target_value='bar_value1', list_of_dictionaries=list_of_dictionaries)
list_of_dictionaries
# -> [{'foo': 'foo_value1', 'bar': 'result_of_calculation'},
# -> {'foo': 'foo_value2', 'bar': 'bar_value2'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question to explain it better

Comment: I've updated the answer. But anyways, I think it would be way easier to create a single dictionary in which the values are tuples with wherever your values are, alongside your local vars, since they seem to be correlated.

Comment: I'm given a list of dictionaries (from the API I am using) so I do not have the option to create the single dictionary.

Comment: Got it! So, is this what you want, or I am missing something?

Comment: I think this will do , the "new_method" function - I really didn't need the inplace but I do appreciate you writing that out.  Is it common to update inplace in python?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what is what you want, but how about this:

```
def myswitch(item,target1,target2,fun1,fun2,default=None,key=None):
    key_item = key(item) if key else item
    if key_item == target1:
        return fun1(item)
    elif key_item == target2:
        return fun2(item)
    else:
        return default
```

this is a generalized switch, that check if the key_item is equal to any of the given targets and if so, apply the corresponding given function, and `key` here is the same as the key argument of the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

Example usage:

```
>>> def do_something_to(x):
        print("doing something to",x )
        return 1

>>> def do_another_thing(x):
        print("doing another thing to",x)
        return 2

>>> list_of_dictionaries = [
    {'foo': 'foo_value1', 'bar': 'bar_value1'},
    {'foo': 'foo_value2', 'bar': 'bar_value2'},
    {'foo': 'foo_value3', 'bar': 'bar_value3'},
]
>>> [ myswitch(x,'bar_value1','bar_value2',do_something_to,do_another_thing, default=23, key=lambda y:y["bar"])
         for x in list_of_dictionaries]
doing something to {'foo': 'foo_value1', 'bar': 'bar_value1'}
doing another thing to {'foo': 'foo_value2', 'bar': 'bar_value2'}
[1, 2, 23]
>>>
```

if those targets values can be used as dictionaries key, you can use a dictionary instead

```
>>> myswitch_dict={'bar_value1':do_something_to, 'bar_value2':do_another_thing}
>>> [ myswitch_dict.get(x["bar"],lambda y:23)(x) for x in list_of_dictionaries]
doing something to {'foo': 'foo_value1', 'bar': 'bar_value1'}
doing another thing to {'foo': 'foo_value2', 'bar': 'bar_value2'}
[1, 2, 23]
>>>
```